# How to check if an instagram account is private or public using webscraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I want to know if an instagram account is private or public by providing the username. It has to be in headless mode as I have to use this in backend.

I tried using beautifulsoup and loaded the target page source but couldn't find anything that specified the account status (private/public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried inspecting the `Network` of a simple GET to my IG profile (private) and a public IG profile. It was very easy to find out this:

In the response of this call:

```
https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=public_account_username
```

The JSON body has this field:

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            // other fields
            "is_private": false,
            // other fields
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, it is set to `true` whether it's private.

You can use both `beautifulsoup` and `requests`, but personally I prefer `requests`. It it very simple performing a `GET` and retrieving data.

But it needs some headers. Looks like this API is only accessible from apps and website, as I've read [here](https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper/issues/544#issuecomment-1043562586).

```
import requests

header = {"User-Agent": "Instagram 219.0.0.12.117 Android"}
username = "your_account"
response = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username={username}", headers=header)
if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
    # user actually exists
    is_private = response["data"]["user"]["is_private"]
```

Comment: There's a typo in the requests.get line : (header -> headers). Works perfectly now. Thanks

Comment: You are absolutely right! I always confuse them. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform multiple operations:

1. Search for a username,
2. Click on it to load its instagram page,
3. Check if that page is private.

All these tasks can be done through [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and a web browser, which allows you testing dynamic websites functionalities.

**CAVEAT:** Please, mind that, although scraping publicly available online information is legal, the usage that you make of that data might not be.